# How to place radiobuttons horizontal in python

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

```py
AANTAL = [(1,"1"),(2,"2"),(3,"3"),(4,"4"),(5,"5"),(6,"6"),]
v= StringVar()
v.set("1")
for text, mode in AANTAL:
    but = Radiobutton(Main,padx=20, pady=10,font=('arial', 20, "bold"), bd=4, text=text, variable=v, value=mode, indicatoron=0)
    but.grid()
```

The above code shows some radiobuttons numbered 1 to 6. However, it displays them vertically instead of horizontally. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

I already tried putting `row=0` in the grid command but this only stacks the buttons on top of each other instead of spreading them out over a row.

Comment: You should read the documentation on the `grid` command before asking such a basic question. `grid` has options that let you specify a specific row and a specific column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid` has two options for placing a widget. `row` *and*  `column`. You need to specify both.

```
buttons = []
vars = []
for idx, (text, mode) in enumerate(AANTAL):
    vars.append(StringVar(value="1"))
    buttons.append(Radiobutton(Main,padx=20, pady=10,font=('arial', 20, "bold"), bd=4, text=text, variable=vars[-1], value=mode, indicatoron=0))
    buttons[-1].grid(row=0, column=idx)
```

Also, when using loops to create widgets, it is much better to store them in a list because you can access them later in your program.