# Displaying Radio buttons horizontally in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I am using the `matplotlib.widgets` to create radio buttons in my widgets, the buttons coming are stacked vertically, I would like them to be stacked horizontally.

MVCE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import RadioButtons
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
rax = plt.axes([0.5,0.05,0.1,0.1])
radio =  RadioButtons(rax ,['1','2','3'], active=0, activecolor='blue' )
plt.show()
```

As you can see with this example you can get the radio buttons like this
[image: Plot with radio buttons stacked vertically],

I am wondering is there a way to stack these radio buttons horizontally.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do this with ```matplotlib.widgets``` ```RadioButtons```, however, it's easy to do directly with tkinter, eg. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45509602/how-to-place-radiobuttons-horizontal-in-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178652/tkinter-pack-geometry-1-column-with-4-radio-buttons-in-one-row)

Comment: @Jack Thanks, actually there is a lot of work that is easy in matplotlib, that's why I am sticking to it, right now I have switched to a Slider rather than radio buttons, but still Radio buttons would be a better option.

Comment: Yes, a ```matplotlib```-only solution to this problem would be nice. Hopefully somebody more knowledgeable than me will come along and solve this for you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is currently an attempt to introduce an `orientation` argument to `RadioButtons` in [PR #13374](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13374); this has not yet been finalized.

As I had commented in this PR, an alternative option would be to use a scatter plot for the buttons. The following shows how I would imagine this implementation. There are two main enhancements compared to the usual buttons:

- Radio buttons are always round independent of the size of the axes.
- They can be aligned arbitrarily, in particular horizontally.

This is achieved by creating a legend internally, which has all the required options readily available. Any valid arguments to `Legend` can be used for the Buttons as well.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import AxesWidget, RadioButtons

class MyRadioButtons(RadioButtons):

    def __init__(self, ax, labels, active=0, activecolor='blue', size=49,
                 orientation="vertical", **kwargs):
        """
        Add radio buttons to an `~.axes.Axes`.
        Parameters
        ----------
        ax : `~matplotlib.axes.Axes`
            The axes to add the buttons to.
        labels : list of str
            The button labels.
        active : int
            The index of the initially selected button.
        activecolor : color
            The color of the selected button.
        size : float
            Size of the radio buttons
        orientation : str
            The orientation of the buttons: 'vertical' (default), or 'horizontal'.
        Further parameters are passed on to `Legend`.
        """
        AxesWidget.__init__(self, ax)
        self.activecolor = activecolor
        axcolor = ax.get_facecolor()
        self.value_selected = None

        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_navigate(False)

        circles = []
        for i, label in enumerate(labels):
            if i == active:
                self.value_selected = label
                facecolor = activecolor
            else:
                facecolor = axcolor
            p = ax.scatter([],[], s=size, marker="o", edgecolor='black',
                           facecolor=facecolor)
            circles.append(p)
        if orientation == "horizontal":
            kwargs.update(ncol=len(labels), mode="expand")
        kwargs.setdefault("frameon", False)    
        self.box = ax.legend(circles, labels, loc="center", **kwargs)
        self.labels = self.box.texts
        self.circles = self.box.legendHandles
        for c in self.circles:
            c.set_picker(5)
        self.cnt = 0
        self.observers = {}

        self.connect_event('pick_event', self._clicked)


    def _clicked(self, event):
        if (self.ignore(event) or event.mouseevent.button != 1 or
            event.mouseevent.inaxes != self.ax):
            return
        if event.artist in self.circles:
            self.set_active(self.circles.index(event.artist))
```

Use it as

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
rax = plt.axes([0.5,0.05,0.4,0.07])
radio =  MyRadioButtons(rax ,['1','2','3'], active=0, activecolor='crimson',
                        orientation="horizontal")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or

```
rax = plt.axes([0.2,0.5,0.25,0.1])
radio =  MyRadioButtons(rax ,["AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"], ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea how to put the legends below the circles? Been playing with bbox_to_anchor at ax.legend with no success so far. How about placing the circles closer to each other?

Comment: @Trmotta How close the circles are is determined foremost by the extent of the `plt.axes` used for this box, if you make it smaller, they are closer together. Any further arguments to `ax.legend()` can be used as well, refer to the `legend` documentation for that. Since legends do not allow for label below the handles, this solution is not very useful for that matter; instead not using a legend would work better in that case. In fact you can refer to the linked PR for a possible alternative option with labels below the circles.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I keep getting
```lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 218, in __set__
    return super().__set__(instance, value)

AttributeError: can't set attribute```

Comment: awesome answer! I ported it to matplotlib >3.3  (fixes the error above)

Answer (score 1):

Since stackexchange does not want this as an edit,
here's an updated version of the above answer from @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that works with recent matplotlib-versions (e.g. >= v3.3)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import AxesWidget, RadioButtons
from matplotlib import cbook

class MyRadioButtons(RadioButtons):

    def __init__(self, ax, labels, active=0, activecolor='blue', size=49,
                 orientation="vertical", **kwargs):
        """
        Add radio buttons to an `~.axes.Axes`.
        Parameters
        ----------
        ax : `~matplotlib.axes.Axes`
            The axes to add the buttons to.
        labels : list of str
            The button labels.
        active : int
            The index of the initially selected button.
        activecolor : color
            The color of the selected button.
        size : float
            Size of the radio buttons
        orientation : str
            The orientation of the buttons: 'vertical' (default), or 'horizontal'.
        Further parameters are passed on to `Legend`.
        """
        AxesWidget.__init__(self, ax)
        self.activecolor = activecolor
        axcolor = ax.get_facecolor()
        self.value_selected = None

        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        ax.set_navigate(False)

        circles = []
        for i, label in enumerate(labels):
            if i == active:
                self.value_selected = label
                facecolor = activecolor
            else:
                facecolor = axcolor
            p = ax.scatter([],[], s=size, marker="o", edgecolor='black',
                           facecolor=facecolor)
            circles.append(p)
        if orientation == "horizontal":
            kwargs.update(ncol=len(labels), mode="expand")
        kwargs.setdefault("frameon", False)    
        self.box = ax.legend(circles, labels, loc="center", **kwargs)
        self.labels = self.box.texts
        self.circles = self.box.legendHandles
        for c in self.circles:
            c.set_picker(5)
        
        self._observers = cbook.CallbackRegistry()
        
        self.connect_event('pick_event', self._clicked)


    def _clicked(self, event):
        if (self.ignore(event) or event.mouseevent.button != 1 or
            event.mouseevent.inaxes != self.ax):
            return
        if event.artist in self.circles:
            self.set_active(self.circles.index(event.artist))
```

Use it as

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
rax = plt.axes([0.5,0.05,0.4,0.07])
radio =  MyRadioButtons(rax ,['1','2','3'], active=0, activecolor='crimson',
                        orientation="horizontal")

plt.show()
```